# How do I concatenate 2 resource strings together in an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a localised ASP.net application (.net 2.0). I wish to concatenate 2 strings retrieved from the resource file together into one element, something like this.

```
Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, lw_name %>" + <%$ Resources:Resource, lw_required %>"
```

I have tried using Eval without success. Is what I am trying to do the "correct" approach or can I store strings with placeholders in the resource file and interpolate them "on the fly".

I am trying to do this in the aspx file rather than in code-behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ASP.NET tag attribute values that use `<%$ Something: Something Else %>` are of a special syntax called [ASP.NET Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx). Using them as attribute values are pretty much all-or-nothing; there's no way to add any code into the ASPX file to manipulate what those expressions evaluate to. You'll have to do this in the code-behind.

Comment: Thanks, I was half expecting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I search for the solution so long
This code works for me:

```
ToolTip='<%# Resources.Global.Btn_Edit + "/" + Resources.Global.Btn_contact %>'
```

Comment: Its use in local resource file but what happen if I used globalization resource file:
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceLabelButton", "CommonPrint")

Answer (score 0):

< asp:HyperLink  ToolTip='<%# "Some Text :" + Eval("id").ToString() %>'  ....../>

Do you mean something like this.... ToolTip='...'    -> Convert your return values to STRING... ( xxxx.ToString() )

Like this it displays:  Some Text: 1234     --> on Tooltip

so you should do something like this in your case:
Text="<%$ (Resources:Resource, lw_name).ToString() %>" + <%$ (Resources:Resource, lw_required).ToString() %>"

I don't know if it's going to work but try to conver to ToString().

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. You get the following error: _'(Resources' expression prefix not recognized_.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried eval but what about something like this:

Text='<%# string.Format("{0}{1}",Eval("lw_name"),Eval("lw_required")) %>'

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and I solved it by using this option instead:

```
Text="<%= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "lw_name") %> <%= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "lw_required") %>"
```

For local Resources, use the GetLocalResourceObject method instead of GetGlobalResourceObject

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`"@(Resources.ResourceString + Resources.ResourceString)"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to append 2 strings in ASPX.

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1}", 
      Resources.file01.string1,Resources.file01.string2)%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This Might Be of Help

```
<asp:Label ID="Mylabel" runat="server">  
  
<%= "before Message String- "+ Resources.MyResources.Message +" -After Message String " %> 

</asp:Label>
```

Note the concatenation is not on the Text attribute but between the label element
Full post can be found [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/how-to-get-the-global-resource-file-values-in-different-loca/)