# Append filename to Img src attribute using resource file

Tags: asp.net, resx

When I try to append the image name onto the end of the `<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, MyKey %>` the server doesn't build the path at all.

This is what I'm doing and it's not working:

```
<img id="Img2" runat="server"  src="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, ImagesPath %>feature_LED.jpg" />
```

Is there any way to append?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET". That's what tags are for.

Comment: According to the answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762979/how-do-i-concatenate-2-resource-strings-together-in-an-aspx-page), you cannot do this from the markup. You'll have to do it from code-behing, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks guys! Sorry for the inappropriate title.

Answer (score 0):

this will work instead

src="<%= Resources.LocalizedText.ImagePath %>