# How can I use DropDownList Tooltip with two resource field like this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I use DropDownList Tooltip with two resource field like this?
Ex I have Two Resource Key:

1. PleaseInuput=Please Input
2. UnderMinistry= Ministry
   and I want to concatenate this to put in my Tooltip to have a result like Please Input Ministry.

[image]

Comment: this question needs improved, explain what you want to achieve, and what is the result of your attempt, not compiled or no effect? and better, some links to the references you used to made the attempt.

Comment: I want to concat two resource key.

Comment: [Here is an answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1763033/815938)

Comment: So that mean we can use two resource in single ToolTip??

Comment: no, according to the accepted answer, you can't do that in aspx, you have to set it in code behind (aspx.cs).